# Building a DBT macro to remove numeric values from a URL

Tags: url, jinja2, dbt

Trying to build a macro that removes numeric values from website URLs. Sample:

- Input: cats.com/232/dryfood/3333
- Output: cats.com/dryfood

To note: Unfortunately, the position of the number changes depending on the url. Sometimes its at the end - cats.com/pets/2322 - sometimes in the middle.

So I built a macro that split the url based on ‘/‘ and put it into a list. We then looped through the list and said “if value contains a number, throw it out, if not, concat to new url string”.

Macro:

```
    {%- set new_url = [] -%}
    {%- set url_chunks = url.split('/') -%}

    {%- for chunk in url_chunks -%}
        {%- if modules.re.match('^([^0-9]*)$', chunk) -%}
            {%- do new_url.append( chunk )-%}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}

    '{{ new_url|join("/") }}' as cleansed

{% endmacro %}
```

Works great when you enter a specific string but when I try to apply the macro to a dbt model, it doesn't work. I.e.:

```
SELECT url,
       url_cleaner('url')
FROM {{ ref('website_model') }}
```

This returns the string value of 'url' instead of the expected output of cats.com/dryfood
Any ideas for how to do this? Or force dbt to fetch the data? Very lost!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to understand that jinja is a templating language. In dbt, we use jinja to automate the creation of sql that then gets executed in our data warehouse. Accordingly, data from your data warehouse does not (typically) flow through your jinja code.

When you call your macro with `url_cleaner('url')`, you are passing the string `"url"` as the argument to your macro. You are **not** passing the data from the column named `url` into your macro.

If you want to split a string that is retrieved from your database, you need to use the SQL `split_parts` operation, not the jinja/python `split`. In other words, your jinja macro needs to write a SQL statement that can execute in your warehouse to operate on your data.

For an example of how to do this, see the [`get_url_path`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils/blob/main/macros/web/get_url_path.sql) macro in dbt-utils. You'll notice it uses the SQL `replace`, `nullif`, and `split_part`:

```sql
{% macro default__get_url_path(field) -%}

    {%- set stripped_url =
        replace(
            replace(field, "'http://'", "''"), "'https://'", "''")
    -%}

    {%- set first_slash_pos -%}
        coalesce(
            nullif({{ position("'/'", stripped_url) }}, 0),
            {{ position("'?'", stripped_url) }} - 1
            )
    {%- endset -%}

    {%- set parsed_path =
        split_part(
            right(
                stripped_url,
                length(stripped_url) ~ "-" ~ first_slash_pos
                ),
            "'?'", 1
            )
    -%}

    {{ safe_cast(
        parsed_path,
        type_string()
    )}}

{%- endmacro %}
```

In your case, if your ID always followed exactly two slashes, your macro could be as simple as:

```sql
{% macro url_cleaner(field) %}
split_part({{ field }}, '/', 3)
{% endmacro %}
```

But I'm sure it's more complex than that, and you'll need to use more SQL to manipulate the url string.